# Twitter cannot fetch content from our domain hosted on an Azure CDN even though it can fetch from an equivalent azureedge.net URL

Tags: twitter, google, dns, azure

There is a website which is distributed via Azure CDN. The CDN endpoint was used as a destination of CNAME entry for `www.< EXAMPLE >.com` with usage of Google DNS. The www address to the website works fine with one exception, twitter cannot resolve the address `https://www.<EXAMPLE>.io`, thereby it cannot read meta tags to generate so called *[twitter card](https://images.app.goo.gl/MXEsTK2qpDa8JN3o9)*. On [the twitter validator page](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) when you try validate above address it will return following message:

*ERROR: Fetching the page failed because the fetcher cannot resolve the address.*

However, when you enter CDN endpoint address (`https://EXAMPLE.azureedge.net`) in the same validator  then everything is fine and Twitter is able to read the website content. Also [facebook sharing debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) doesn't complain.

Below you can see obscure `dig` output for `www.EXAMPLE.io` domain.

```
www.EXAMPLE.io.     60                      IN CNAME    EXAMPLE.azureedge.net.
EXAMPLE.azureedge.net. 1799                 IN CNAME    EXAMPLE.afd.azureedge.net.
EXAMPLE.afd.azureedge.net. 299              IN CNAME    afd.t-XXXX.t-msedge.net.
afd.t-XXXX.t-msedge.net. 200                IN CNAME    t-XXXX.t-msedge.net.
t-XXXX.t-msedge.net.    43                  IN CNAME    XXXXXXXXXXXXX.ctrl.t-XXXX.t-msedge.net.
XXXXXXXXXXXXX.ctrl.t-XXXX.t-msedge.net. 223 IN CNAME    standard.t-XXXX.t-msedge.net.
standard.t-XXXX.t-msedge.net. 236           IN A        1.2.3.4
```

What can cause the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Seven DNS lookups until you get to an IP address?  That seems excessive to me.  I don't know if there is a limit, but it would seem prudent to avoid that many CNAMEs to me.

Comment: Hi @StephenOstermiller. Exactly, that was the first thing I thought but I don't have that possibility in Azure CDN. Those entries are done by Azure itself, it's a part of the service.

Comment: Maybe you could try switching to an ALIAS record set: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-alias

Comment: @StephenOstermiller in upcoming days we will try to do it using Azure DNS and ALIAS entry. I'll report back here how it went.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that Azure has 3 different types of CDNs. Microsoft, Verizon and Akamai, and only Verizon and Akamai work with twitter resolver.

You need to switch Microsoft Azure CDN to Verizon or Akamai to solve this issue.

Comment: I'm running into this exact issue too. I raised it with the Product team - if you want to get it prioritized, help me upvote here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/40389646-allow-azure-cdn-to-display-the-twitter-card